# How to replace default code in arduino bootloader

Tags: arduino, avr, bootloader, arduino-ide, atmega

I need to make bootloader with my code.

[I discovered a github](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/bootloaders) with bootloaders, but i don't know what to do with it. 
My experience in use of arduino is limited by [burning the default bootloader for ATmega328p](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard)

So, is there any simple way just to replace default arduino bootloader code (blinking diod) to anything else?

Comment: blinking LED does not have anything common with bootloader

Comment: Arduino default bootloader comes with small sketch (code), that allows to blink pin 15 (internal arduino led)

Answer (score 4):

Certainly there is.  Embedded engineers replace and/or overwrite the bootloaders all the time.  [Here's an article on the subject](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader) but I'll outline the basics.

1. Select a progamming device.  There are numerous devices on the market, from very inexpensive to quite expensive, depending on what else they can do besides program a chip.  You can even use another Arduino as a programmer, probably least expensive of all and readily available.
2. Connect the programmer to the proper programming pins.  For your purposes you'll want the ISP/ICSP headers (2x3 header(s)) on the board, or 2x3 connector to an non-Arduino programmer.
3. Upload your code using the Arduino IDE, a utility such as AVRdude, or even Atmel Studio if you're very ambitious and want complete control.

It's not that hard if you use another Arduino as your programmer and 6 female-female jumper wires as outlined in the article.